# О прилагательных перед дефисной парой

Tags: грамматика

**Из разговора:** Помнишь, у нас работал Саша? Ну, маленький такой очкарик-лаборант.

Правильно записана фраза? А если ее изменить: Ну, маленький такой лаборант-очкарик.

**Какой вариант лучше и почему? Или нет разницы?**

Answer (score 1):

> > Ну, маленький такой очкарик-лаборант.

Ну, маленький такой очкарик лаборант.

> > А если ее изменить: Ну, маленький такой лаборант-очкарик.

Можно и изменить. Тогда через дефис. Как старик отец и отец-старик.

Comment: А заголовок читали? Ну там ещё  слово "прилагательных" было?  И сравнить надо на слух две полные фразы. Попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: Читал, а как же. "Правильно записана фраза?" А про слух где? А прилагательные при чем? Фраза записана неправильно. А на слух — это уж как произнести. С понижением тона или с повышением... или вообще с паузами.

Comment: Там две фразы, какая вам кажется неправильной?  Наличие прилагательных как-нибудь влияет на порядок слов в дефисной паре?

Comment: Первая неправильная, вторая правильная. Нет, не влияет. Еще раз: то же, что "старик отец" (без дефиса) и "отец-старик" (через дефис).

Comment: Уже лучше, а теперь объясните, почему первая неправильная, а вторая правильная. Вы считаете, что неправильно "очкарик-лаборант"?  А почему? Лопатин теперь всё через дефис пишет. Кстати, и по старым правилам здесь возможен дефис. Это зависит от того, что мы считаем главным словом. Девушкам не так интересно, что Саша лаборант, для них важнее, что он очкарик, тогда лаборант - это приложение в постпозиции.

Comment: @Sibylla Извините, а разве "такой" - прилагательное? По-моему, это местоимение.

Comment: Ну, лопатинские правила я плохо знаю.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Такой - местоименное прилагтельное.

Comment: А в общем я вот что хочу сказать: первое оценочное существительное из дефисной пары вполне может иметь собственный ряд прилагательных-определений, согласованных с ним,  поэтому "чудненький очкарик-лаборантка" мне уже не кажется отступлением от правил, а является обычной грамматической нормой.

Comment: Все, что угодно, можно оправдать, тем более если "классик". Только зачем? У поэзии свои законы, им, поэтам, академическая грамматика не указ.

Comment: @ Sibylla, что неясного? У Розенталя ведь этот пункт оговаривается.

Answer (score 0):

Я исхожу из того, что в каждой дефисной паре существительных есть главное (определяемое) слово и прилагательное должно относиться к нему. При таком подходе "чудненький очкарик-лаборантка" тоже может считаться правильным, но тогда надо считать что очкарик - определяемое слово. А вот такое объяснение, что дескать существительное-приложение из дефисной пары "вполне может иметь собственный ряд прилагательных-определений" мне кажется странным, потому что  странно видеть дефис, соединяющий многословное приложение с определяемым словом. Дефис хорош для однословных приложений, а для многословных он заменяется на тире. Это хорошо видно, когда  приложение идет за определяемым словом: "лаборантка-очкарик" -> "лаборантка - чудненький очкарик".

Comment: Эта тема у Розенталя: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm §93.пункт 2, примечание 2 Обособленные приложения В некоторых случаях возможно дефисное написание и при наличии пояснительного слова (определения), которое по смыслу может относиться или ко всему сочетанию (известный экспериментатор-изобретатель, ловкий акробат-жонглер), или только к определяемому слову (демобилизованный воин-сверхсрочник, оригинальный художник-самоучка, моя соседка-педагог), или только к приложению (женщина-врач с большим стажем).